# Как реализовать смешанный тип поиска в query_string режиме в ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Доброго времени суток!

Появилась у меня потребность сделать смешанный тип поиска в режиме `query_string`. Чтобы обрабатывался, к примеру, вот такой поисковый запрос:

> проснитесь и пойте "мистер фримен"

В этом случае ожидается, что фраза в кавычках преобразуется в токен с точно тем же содержимым, а остальные слова преобразуются в токен по общим правилам (опустится предлог `в`, т.к. он входит в список стоп-слов в русском языке, а слова `проснитесь` и `пойте` преобразуются в токены в соответствии с правилами русского языка). Ну и далее, поиск должен производиться по двум полям в документе (`question` и `answer` - см. ниже) и с использованием оператора `AND`.
В данный момент все работает без кавычек, как и должно, однако если в запросе присутствует фраза в кавычках - запрос выполняется, будто этих кавычек нет вовсе (экранирование кавычек не влияет на результат в данном случае).
Ниже привожу свои настройки в виде словаря Python:

```py
INDEX_SETTINGS = {
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "ru_stop": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords": [],
                },
                "ru_stemmer": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "language": "russian",
                },
            },
            "char_filter": {
                "e_char_filter": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": ["Ё => Е", "ё => е"],
                },
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "e_ru": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "ru_stop",
                        "ru_stemmer",
                    ],
                    "char_filter": ["e_char_filter"],
                },
                "q_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                    ],
                    "char_filter": ["e_char_filter"],
                }
            },
        },
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "realid": {
                "type": "integer",
            },
            "timestamp": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            },
            "scale": {
                "type": "float",
            },
            "question": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "e_ru",
                "search_analyzer": "e_ru",
                "search_quote_analyzer": "q_analyzer",
            },
            "answer": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "e_ru",
                "search_analyzer": "e_ru",
                "search_quote_analyzer": "q_analyzer",
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Список `stopwords` заполняется отдельно.
Далее структура самого запроса:

```py
INDEX_SEARCH = {
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "fields": ["question", "answer"],
                    "query": '',
                    "type": "cross_fields",
                    "default_operator": "and",
                    "analyzer": "e_ru",
                    "quote_analyzer": "q_analyzer",
                },
            },
            "functions": [{
                "field_value_factor": {
                  "field": "scale",
                  "factor": 1,
                  "missing": 1.0,
                },
            }],
        },
    },
    "sort": [],
    "highlight": {
        "pre_tags": ["<b>"],
        "post_tags": ["</b>"],
        "fields": {
            "question": {},
            "answer": {},
        },
    },
}
```

`query` и `sort` заполняются отдельно.

Что нужно сделать для корректного выполнения запроса, если он содержит данные в кавычках?

Заранее благодарен за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Проблем с маппингом я не вижу. У Вас, скорее всего, проблема с построением запроса.

```
GET name-of-index/_validate/query?explain=true
```

```json
{
  "query": {
        "query_string": {
                "fields": ["question", "answer"],
                "query": "<your query>",
                "type": "cross_fields",
                "default_operator": "and",
                "analyzer": "e_ru",
                "quote_analyzer": "q_analyzer",
        },
  }
}
```

Этот запрос поможет нам увидеть, как Elasticsearch переводит запрос к Lucene виду. Для примера из официальной документации это будет выглядеть так:

```
GET my-index-000001/_validate/query?explain=true
```

```json
{
   "query":{
      "query_string":{
         "query":"the also \"the quick brown fox\"",
         "default_operator": "and"
      }
   }
}
```

```
{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "valid" : true,
  "explanations" : [
    {
      "index" : "my-index-000001",
      "valid" : true,
      "explanation" : """+title:also +title:"the quick brown fox""""
    }
  ]
}
```

Если мы видим, что есть скобки для `+title:"the quick brown fox"` — с запросом проблем нет и нужно копать маппинг. В противном случае есть проблемы либо с экранированием либо с чем-то подобным.

Добавьте ответ команды `_validate`, и мы продолжим поиск проблемы.